# Condicion Count MySQL cuando se cumpla una condicion en otra fila

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Quiero realizar el conteo en la tabla referidos cuando `referidos.pago` sea `true`.

¿Me pueden ayudar?

```
SELECT usuarios.id, 
       usuarios.serialuser,
       usuarios.nombre,
       usuarios.apellido,
       count(referidos.cod_user) as TotalRef,
       usuarios.fecha_ingreso, usuarios.pago
FROM usuarios LEFT JOIN referidos ON referidos.cod_user = usuarios.serialuser
GROUP BY referidos.cod_user, usuarios.nombre
ORDER BY "TotalRef" ASC
```

Tengo una tabla usuarios y una referidos.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 0):

En caso que la consulta te funcione, para hacer referencia a los count de cuando referidos.pago sea tru, tienes que hacer una condición en la consulta indicándolo.

La condición sería de esta manera

```
 where referidos.pago is not null
```

Esta condición lo que hace es que te hace el conteo de los datos que tu eliges siempre y cuando `referidos.pago` como indicas arriba tenga valor, es decir no tenga valores `null`.

En la consulta que adjuntas el código quedaría de esta manera.

```
SELECT
    usuarios.id,
    usuarios.serialuser,
    usuarios.nombre,
    usuarios.apellido,
    COUNT(referidos.cod_user) AS totalref,
    usuarios.fecha_ingreso,
    usuarios.pago
FROM
    usuarios
LEFT JOIN
    referidos
ON
    referidos.cod_user = usuarios.serialuser
    where referidos.pago is not null
GROUP BY
    referidos.cod_user,
    usuarios.nombre
ORDER BY
    "TotalRef" ASC;
```

Espero que le sea de ayuda, un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte un tiempo para ayudarme. Resulta que esa condición filtra toda la búsqueda ya que le estamos diciendo que traiga esos datos cuando referidos.pago = true, y lo que yo quiero es que el Count se realice cuado referidos.pago = true, para tener una suma al cumplirse esa condición.